# How to replace/bypass a class property?

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I would like to have a class with an attribute `attr` that, when accessed for the first time, runs a function and returns a value, and then *becomes* this value (its type changes, etc.).

A similar behavior can be obtained with:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def attr(self):
        try:
            return self._cached_result
        except AttributeError:
            result = ...
            self._cached_result = result
            return result

obj = MyClass()
print obj.attr  # First calculation
print obj.attr  # Cached result is used
```

However, `.attr` does not *become* the initial result, when doing this. It would be more efficient if it did.

A difficulty is that after `obj.attr` is set to a property, it cannot be set easily to something else, because infinite loops appear naturally. Thus, in the code above, the `obj.attr` property has no setter so it cannot be directly modified. If a setter is defined, then replacing `obj.attr` in this setter creates an infinite loop (the setter is accessed from within the setter). I also thought of first *deleting* the setter so as to be able to do a regular `self.attr = …`, with `del self.attr`, but this calls the property deleter (if any), which recreates the infinite loop problem (modifications of `self.attr` anywhere generally tend to go through the property rules).

So, is there a way to bypass the property mechanism and replace the bound property `obj.attr` by anything, from within `MyClass.attr.__getter__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a bit like premature optimization : you want to skip a method call by making a descriptor change itself.

It's perfectly possible, but it would have to be justified.

To modify the descriptor from your property, you'd have to be editing your class, which is probably not what you want.

I think a better way to implement this would be to :

- do not define `obj.attr`
- override `__getattr__`, if argument is "attr", `obj.attr = new_value`, otherwise raise `AttributeError`

As soon as `obj.attr` is set, `__getattr__` will not be called any more, as it is only called when the attribute does not exist. (`__getattribute__` is the one that would get called all the time.)

The main difference with your initial proposal is that the first attribute access is slower, because of the method call overhead of `__getattr__`, but then it will be as fact as a regular `__dict__` lookup.

**Example :**

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'attr':
            self.attr = ...
            return self.attr
        raise AttributeError(name)

obj = MyClass()
print obj.attr  # First calculation
print obj.attr  # Cached result is used
```

**EDIT :** Please see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879250/1011859), especially if you use Python 3.6 or more.

Comment: I was just writing the same thing, I will upvote yours instead, this works perfectly fine !

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I understand the part "to modify the descriptor from your property, you'd have to be editing your class": in fact, what is needed is not an update of the class itself (that would break the calculation of `attr` for new instances), but an update of the `attr` attribute of an _instance_. Right?

Comment: No,  because as long as `attr` is both **defined on the class** AND **a data descriptor**, it will be used instead. Python attribute lookup order can be a bit tricky, [here is some more reading on the subject](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/AttributeLookupOrder).

Answer (score 1):

For new-style classes, which utilize the descriptor protocol, you could do this by creating your own custom descriptor class whose `__get__()` method will be called at most one time. When that happens, the result is then cached by creating an instance attribute with the same name the class method has.

Here's what I mean.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class cached_property(object):
    """Descriptor class for making class methods lazily-evaluated and caches the result."""
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        else:
            value = self.func(inst)
            setattr(inst, self.func.__name__, value)
            return value

class MyClass(object):
    @cached_property
    def attr(self):
        print('doing long calculation...', end='')
        result = 42
        return result

obj = MyClass()
print(obj.attr)  # -> doing long calculation...42
print(obj.attr)  # -> 42
```

Comment: Does this not do pretty much exactly what you wanted? Properties are just descriptor instances.

Comment: This also does exactly what OP wanted, but would be nicer in Python 3.6 where it can use `__set_name__` instead of using `__name__` which might do unexpected things in the presence of other decorators.

Comment: This is also a better fix to OP's problem : he tried "deleting" the setter, while it just had to not be defined at first, using a descriptor instead of `property`. I believe this should be the accepted answer.